# facing connection refused error while trying to run test cases from one container which is hitting the zalenium container

Tags: java, selenium, docker, dockerfile, zalenium

When running my selenium testcases on Zalenium grid locally and it runs fine. I have created image of my project using the docker file below. i have written the docker compose file to start the zalenium grid . But when trying to run image of my project to create container and run test cases inside my container it is giving connection refused error.

**Dockerfile of my project to create image is below**

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.1-debian
VOLUME /tmp
ADD web_runnable.jar app.jar
ADD cacerts cacerts
ADD config.properties config
EXPOSE 8000
ENV USERNAME xyz
ENV PASSWORD xyz
ENV GRID true
ENTRYPOINT sh -c 'java -jar -Dconfig=config -DuserName=$USERNAME -Dpassword=$PASSWORD  -Dgrid=$GRID -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=cacerts /app.jar com.tsys.driverscript.DriverScript.class'
```

**Docker compose file to start zalenium is below**

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  zalenium:
    image: dosel/zalenium
    container_name: zalenium_container
    networks:
      - main    
    restart:  always
    ports:
     - "4444:4444"
    command: ["start", "--desiredContainers", "1", "--maxDockerSeleniumContainers", "1","--sauceLabsEnabled","false","--screenWidth", "1280", "--screenHeight", "720" , --timeZone , "Asia/Kolkata", "--seleniumImageName","elgalu/selenium:latest"]
    volumes:
     - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
     - /Users/nikitatorane/videos:/home/seluser/videos   
    privileged: true

  selenium:
    image: elgalu/selenium:latest
    container_name: selenium_container
    networks:
      - main
    restart:  always
networks:
  main: 
    name: main
```

**I have setup my huburl as below :**

```
NODE = "http://zalenium:4444/wd/hub";
```

When I'm trying to run image using with setting the same network on which zalenium is running then also i am getting connection refused error being all containers in same network.

**Command to build image of my project is below :**
`docker build -t xyz:1.2`

**command to run my project image is below :**
`docker run -it --net=main xyz:1.2`

**error while running image is below :***

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)
        at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:74)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
        ... 52 more
```

I even tried to link two containers and then also getting same error as above. Can anyone go through this and let me know where I am going wrong ?

Comment: How are you telling the 2nd container where to find the Zalenium container?

Comment: I was able to run test cases in zalenium container by placing all containers in same network and linking them together